# Android2.2 url connect exception

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I have the following code for url connect, which throws an exception but the exception object is empty. how to connect to a url without any exception in android 2.2

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection= null;
URL url = null;
    try
    {
     url = new URL(urlString.toString());
     urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
     urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
     urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
     urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
     urlConnection.connect();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {//ex is empty here}
```

Comment: If you put `Log.d("TAG", ex.getMessage());` does it appear at logcat?

Comment: yes. it shows at log cat as network on main thread exception

Comment: Can you tell us what it the exception?

Comment: are you declare internet permission in manifest?

Comment: exception = android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: i have already set internet permission in manifest

Answer (score 0):

I think a get-request does not like when output is enabled. In this case you should
not set:

```
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
```